# Swapping names(malloced ones) using non malloced pointer variable

Tags: c, pointers, memory, malloc, dynamic-allocation

I am getting confused with pointers. Here is a code to swap two names. Please see the code. Consider Input : hellohai(for d) and asd(for e).
Output i am getting : asd      1ellohai        1ellohai

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
        char *d,*e,*f;


        d=(char*)malloc(10);
        e=(char*)malloc(5);

        scanf("%s",d);
        scanf("%s",e);

        f=d;
        d=e;   
        e=f; //while printing e it prints the whole value contained in f (i.e.1ellohai). How? size of e is 5 only

        f[0]='1'; // f is in read-only memory. So this should fail?
        printf("%s \t %s \t %s \n",d,e,f);


        return 0;
}
```

Comment: `f[0]` is *not* readonly. It is assigned `d` which points to malloced memory, which is always writable.

Comment: so you mean if i do something like f="hello" then only it is in read only. What about the value of e?

Comment: f itself is not readonly, either.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: The size of the thing `e` *originally* pointed to was 5; after the swapping, what it points to is size 10 (what was originally pointed to by `d`).  The sizes of `e` and `d` themselves (the pointers) don't change.

Comment: Yes; the memory for string literals used to initialize pointer-to-char is readonly (`char *foo="bar"`). It is read/write for arrays-of-char, e.g. `char foo[]="bla";`

Comment: donjuedo: see the comments inside code

Comment: It works as I would expect it to.  `e` originally pointed to the block of 5, and after the pointer swap, `e` points to the block of 10.  Vice versa for d.  Why do you say `f` is read only?  Is it on a custom board and in ROM somehow?  For a normal PC, with the code we see, `f` can be changed, as well as the contents `f` points to.

Comment: donjuedo: I thought f is read only because its not malloced. So even if e points to a block of 10, i can't write more than 5bytes inside e(because e's size is 5). Correct me if i am wrong?

Comment: If you do `char *f = "hello";`  then (initially) `f` points to memory that you are not supposed to modify.  Whether the system will *enforce* that is not specified.  A good compiler ought to warn, though, about dropping `const` qualification.  The correct declaration would be `const char *f = "hello";`.

Comment: I've said it before, but [please don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are swapping pointers what you are swapping is the memory location that is in the pointer variable.  `f` has the old value of `d` and is pointing to the memory allocated via `malloc`.  Therefore

```
f[0]='1'; // f is in read-only memory. So this should fail?
```

Is incorrect.

Second to explain the output.  Before you swap you basically have `d` pointing to a string containing `"hellohai"` and `e` pointing to a string containing `"asd"`.  After the swap `f` and `e` point to a string containing `"hellohai"` and `d` points to a string containing `"asd"`.  You then modifying the string that `f` and `e` are pointing to through `f` so the now that is `"1ellohai"`.  You then print everything, and the output is as expected.

Memory allocated by `malloc` is writable.  What you are probably confusing this with is the following:

```
char *f = "hello";
f[0] = '1';
```

This is a bad idea and leads to undefined behavior.

Finally, as a caveat in C [it is generally not a good idea to cast the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Answer (score 3):

When you do this:

```
    d=(char*)malloc(10);
    e=(char*)malloc(5);
```

`d` points to a 10 byte buffer, and `e` points to a 5 byte buffer.

Then you have this:

```
    f=d;    // f now points to the 10 byte buffer
    d=e;    // d now points to the 5 byte buffer
    e=f;    // e now points to the 10 byte buffer
```

You're not actually copying the strings from one to the other.  You're really changing the pointers.

Then when you do this:

```
f[0]='1';
```

It changes the first byte of the 10 byte buffer.  `f` is not read-only because it is pointing to the same malloc'ed buffer that `d` originally (and now `e`) pointed to.

Answer (score 0):

```
    d=(char*)malloc(10);   //buffer for 10 chars 
    e=(char*)malloc(5);    //buffer for 5 chars
```

These are not size of pointers `d` and `e`(You should see their size using `sizeof` operator.).

The only thing that change is that what these points to . These

```
    f=d;
    d=e;   
    e=f;
```

actually don't copy string's . This just changes to what the pointers point.
    f[0]='1';   // This is correct and is re-writable . Don't confuse it with string literal

For some safety -

1.Don't cast result of `malloc`.

2.These `scanf`'s shoud be -

```
    scanf("%9s",d);
    scanf("%4s",e);
```

as to prevent case when you enter chars more that `9` or `4` which will casue *UB*

3.`free` the memory you allocate .

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that you're `malloc`ing two memory blocks. Those blocks have address, which `d` and `e` holds. To confirm that, put these after your `scanf`s.

```
printf ("Address of d: %p\n", &d);
printf ("Address of e: %p\n", &e);
printf ("Address of block d(value of d): %p\n", d);
printf ("Address of block e(value of e): %p\n", e);
```

My output is:

```
Address of d: 0x7fff037a5488
Address of e: 0x7fff037a5490
Address of block d(value of d): 0xa8e010
Address of block e(value of e): 0xa8e030
```

Now, when you make the swap between the pointers, all you're doing is changing the *memory block references*, not the actual pointer address (which you **can't do**).

You can confirm that by putting those `printf` after the swaps, like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
        char *d,*e,*f;


        d=(char*)malloc(10);
        e=(char*)malloc(5);

        scanf("%s",d);
        scanf("%s",e);


    printf ("Address of d: %p\n", &d);
    printf ("Address of e: %p\n", &e);
    printf ("Address of f: %p\n", &f);
    printf ("Address of block d(value of d): %p\n", d);
    printf ("Address of block e(value of e): %p\n", e);

        f=d;
        d=e;   
        e=f; //while printing e it prints the whole value contained in f (i.e.1ellohai). How? size of e is 5 only

    printf ("Address of d: %p\n", &d);
    printf ("Address of e: %p\n", &e);
    printf ("Address of f: %p\n", &f);
    printf ("Address of block d(value of d): %p\n", d);
    printf ("Address of block e(value of e): %p\n", e);
    printf ("Address of block f(value of f): %p\n", f);

        f[0]='1'; // f is in read-only memory. So this should fail?
        printf("%s \t %s \t %s \n",d,e,f);


        return 0;
}
```

And the output:

```
$ ./draft
hellohai
asd
Address of d: 0x7ffebae87d78
Address of e: 0x7ffebae87d80
Address of f: 0x7ffebae87d88
Address of block d(value of d): 0x2143010
Address of block e(value of e): 0x2143030
Address of d: 0x7ffebae87d78
Address of e: 0x7ffebae87d80
Address of f: 0x7ffebae87d88
Address of block d(value of d): 0x2143030
Address of block e(value of e): 0x2143010
Address of block f(value of f): 0x2143010
asd      1ellohai    1ellohai
```

From this you can see that:

- 1. The **addresses** of the pointers never changed.
- 2. The **references** (their values) changed. They got swaped.
- 3. `e` and `f` point to the same memory block. That's why doing `f[0]='1'` changes the value printed by both.

---

### A primitive memory layout

After you declare your variables, you memory will look like this:

```
Values     : | - | - | - |   |   |   | 
Variable   : | d | e | f |   |   |   | 
Memory(hex): | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
```

When you malloc, your computer gives `d` the block at address **5** and `e` the block at address **6**, so now it looks like this:

```
Values     : | 5 | 6 | - |   |   |   | 
Variable   : | d | e | f |   |   |   | 
Memory(hex): | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
```

After you read your strings, the *contents* of the blocks at **5** and **6** will get written:

```
Values     : | 5 | 6 | - |   | hellohai | asd | 
Variable   : | d | e | f |   |          |     | 
Memory(hex): | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |    5     |  6  |
```

When you print `d`, it access the memory address it points to (**5** in this case) and print the contents. Same for the `e` variable.

Now, when you **swap** the values doing:

```
f=d;

Values     : | 5 | 6 | 5 |   | hellohai | asd | 
Variable   : | d | e | f |   |          |     | 
Memory(hex): | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |    5     |  6  |

d=e;

Values     : | 6 | 6 | 5 |   | hellohai | asd | 
Variable   : | d | e | f |   |          |     | 
Memory(hex): | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |    5     |  6  |

e=f;

Values     : | 6 | 5 | 5 |   | hellohai | asd | 
Variable   : | d | e | f |   |          |     | 
Memory(hex): | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |    5     |  6  |
```

Now `e` and `f` point to the same place (where `d` *used to* point) and `d` points to where `e` *used to* point. It's **important to note** that the actual **values** of the addresses **5** and **6 never got touched**.

And when you do:

```
f[0]='1';
```

You're telling the computer to access the first byte of the contents of the memory block at address **5** and change it. So now you have:

```
Values     : | 6 | 5 | 5 |   | 1ellohai | asd | 
Variable   : | d | e | f |   |          |     | 
Memory(hex): | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |    5     |  6  |
```

This is a very simple representation of what you memory might look like so you can get the idea of how it works.